# 'Consolidating figure' is a non-existent phrase. What could I use instead?

Tags: word-request

What could I use to denote a person who manages to gather around himself people of every hue to, say, fight for some common cause despite differences? I need some two-word phrase but, unlike mine, one that is actually in usage and not some made-up nonsense. I believe 'figure' is okay, I can keep it, can't I?

Comment: Perhaps a ***unifying coalition** leader?*

Comment: ... Exactly how you express the concept will partly depend on whether you want to imply ***admiration*** (for his "people skills" in attracting support from superficially incompatible groups), or ***disdain*** (for his incoherent "rag-bag" of disparate supporters, likely to fall apart due to irreconcilable internal differences).

Comment: No, I mean in a positive or neutral way

Comment: But there's nothing wrong with *she was a consolidating figure* … In fact, Googling it finds several pieces of writing that actually use the phrase. [Here](https://books.google.com/books?id=ND8PBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA55&lpg=PA55&dq=%22consolidating+figure%22&source=bl&ots=Ilc7mTuz4N&sig=ACfU3U1CdD4YDVtPH_gan3FL80-A7r4jRQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiNtY-o6fflAhWqpFkKHVk6DTAQ6AEwA3oECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22consolidating%20figure%22&f=false), for example. (Not that it would be wrong if it didn't.)

Comment: I characterized it that way because dictionaries (Lexico, Longman) don't list that sense in their respective entries for 'consolidate'